# an icon of fear and fascination

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The word "fascination" has two senses in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary:

> a very strong attraction, that makes something very interesting

> the state of being very attracted to and interested in somebody/something

Which sense is intended in the following sentence, which concerns the funnel-web spider?

> although no deaths have been recorded since the introduction of an antivenom in 1981, it remains an icon of fear and **fascination** for Sydneysiders.

https://australian.museum/learn/animals/spiders/funnel-web-spiders-group/

Comment: ***fascination*** has a range of meanings. You should probably downplay the relevance of ***attractive*** in your cited context, which explicitly "primes" the reader's interpretation with preceding ***fear***. It's the "Rabbit transfixed in the headlights" kind of fascination - implying ***danger***. Sydneysiders don't really *want* to think about antivenom (because it makes them think about potentially lethal snakebite), but it fascinates them (they can't easily turn their attention aside; it's like a magic spell "transfixing" them).

Comment: ,,, oh, okay. The "fascinating icon" is the funnel-web spider, not the antivenom. But you can see my point, I hope.

Comment: Does "fascination" mean the state of being transfixed or the quality of transfixing someone in this context?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. How would the overall meaning of the cited text change depending on which of your definitions you applied? Or are you asking some technical question about "parts of speech" (which I *also* couldn't answer! :)

Comment: If something is an icon of X, does it have X or cause X?

Comment: We're far more likely to say something is [*an icon of **hope***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+icon+of+hope%2Can+icon+of+fear&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) than *...of **fear***. So I'll base my analysis on that, because it's more familiar to me. All sorts of things can be icons of hope (not just *people*, who can experience hope or fear). So [*A **rainbow** is an icon of hope*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22rainbow+is+an+icon%22), but what would it mean to say a rainbow "has" hope? And why would a funnel-web spider have fear?

Comment: A spider cannot cause fascination. It is the source or target of the fascination that people feel,

Comment: Ask yourself if 'fear' means that the object possesses fear as a quality, or invokes it in others, and that will give you your answer.

Comment: @YosefBaskin How do you mean, "A spider cannot cause fascination"? I'm sure arachnologists would line up to tell you otherwise.

Comment: @Apollyon To clarify, you understand that it's Sydneysiders who feel the fascination, and you're asking whether in this context, "fascination" refers to the feeling Sydneysiders have about the spiders, or the power that the spiders have to cause that feeling in them. Is that right?

Comment: @gotube Yes, that's what I'm asking. I understand spiders have the ability to inspire fascination in people, and if the context didn't include the phrase "an icon of," I'd readily take "fascination" to refer to such an ability/quality. However, if "an icon of" can be taken to mean "a prototypical exemplar that **causes** a particular feeling," then "fascination" seems to mean the feelings people have about something.

Comment: So the question hinges on the interpretation "an icon of." To complicate matters further, the word "fear" also has the meaning "to ability to inspire fear" in the Shorter Oxford English Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is badly written, but can be parsed to make sense, with some stretching.

In the phrase, "X is an icon of Z", "of" indicates that *X represents Z*. This structure and function is part of the *lexical entry* of the word "icon", not how "of" normally functions.

Compare this with the phrase "***a creature/beast/insect/thing** of fear and fascination*", where "of" clearly means that it has the power to inspire fear and fascination in others. This is the normal meaning of "of". It does not indicate representation of fear or fascination here.

So, if we parse the word "of" in the original with the meaning in the paragraph above, it means that the funnel-web spider is an icon (of something not mentioned), and that it inspires fear and fascination. With this parsing, it would not mean that it is iconic of fear and fascination.

We can imagine that the sentence was originally written with "thing", but someone decided that "icon" was a more interesting word, and didn't check that it still made sense.

So, an unfortunate error with the special function of "of" after the word "icon", which is different from its normal function after most other nouns.

Comment: Do you mean that "X is an icon of Y" indicates X has the property of Y, and that the original is not well written because it conveys that the funnel-web spider has fear?

Comment: @Apollyon Outside this sentence, "X is an icon of Z" means "X is a symbol that people generally understand as representing Z". It doesn't mean that the two share any properties. A spider doesn't have the properties of a city, for instance. It's simply a symbol associated with the city. THAT SAID, something can be an icon of something because it has that property, like Angelina Jolie being an icon of beauty. But it's also possible for there to be no connection whatsoever, like a big apple being iconic of New York City.

Comment: Thank you. So why is it incorrect to say the funnel-web spider is an icon of fear, meaning that it represents fear? What about calling it an icon of horror?

Comment: @Apollyon It certainly can, and I hope I haven't suggested it couldn't. What I said was that that's not the meaning in your example sentence. We know that because the spider is definitely not an icon of fascination. That's to say, nobody considers the spider as an iconic symbol representing fascination. That's how we know it also doesn't mean it's an icon of fear.

Comment: So you are saying the spider doesn't represent fear? Is there any semantic reason for that? Does it make sense to say the spider represents horror?

Comment: @Apollyon *In your example sentence*, the spider does not represent fear. There's a couple steps to my logic. 1) For semantic reasons, I know the spider doesn't represent fascination. 2) Because of the grammar structure, I know that the spider doesn't represent "fear and fascination". 3) Because of this, it doesn't represent fear. I believe the sentence's original meaning is: "*...it remains an icon **of Sydney**, **and causes** fear and fascination for Sydneysiders.*

Comment: What are the semantic reasons?

Comment: @Apollyon The semantic reason is that it makes no sense, at least not to me, that the funnel-web spider represents fascination. The spider may also inspire curiosity, or funny anecdotes, but the spider itself doesn't *represent* any of those things.